# Find and replace with grep and perl

Tags: terminal, perl

I'd like to grep and replace specific text in textfiles within a directory and all subdirs.  I try the following:

```
ls -R | egrep '.*\.txt' | perl -i -p -e 's/one.a/two.a/g'
```

Although grep spits out a list and this executes, I can't seem to get perl to actually write to the files.  If possible, I'm interested in learning how to do this without the use of `find`.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
jml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two minor issues:  First, to pipe file names to a perl one-liner in this way, you need to use the [xargs](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/06/10-xargs-command-example-in-linux-unix.html) command.

Second, you will need to pass the full path to the perl one-liner, because it might be in a subdir, so it would be better to use `find`.

Here's a working command:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs perl -i -p -e 's/one.a/two.a/g'
```

Comment: can i not do this with ls / grep?

Comment: It's not impossible to get full path's including recursive subdirs from `ls`, but `find` is much simpler.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767384/ls-command-how-can-i-get-a-recursive-full-path-listing-one-line-per-file